# Softlayer api for Block storage deletion request immediately

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are building a implementation where we can delete all the block sotrage including performance & endurance with selected billing ID, I have used the following softlayer rest api for cancellation of storage for our implementation
"https://api.softlayer.com//SoftLayer_Billing_Item/billingID/cancelItem"
Softlayer team told that if i will like to have my services removed immediately, i will need to update the request accordingly with my intention. So, what is the extra parameter should i give in that mentioned api to cancel the request immediately.

Regards,
Debartha

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/[billingItemID]/cancelItem

Method: POST

Json Payload:

{
  "parameters": [
    true,
    false,
    "No longer needed",
    "Cancel immediately"
  ]
}
```

The first property as `true` will cancel the item immediately. Please see the SLDN reference [SoftLayer_Billing_Item::cancelItem](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/cancelItem)

To get the `billingItemID`, please execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/[StorageID]/getBillingItem
Method: GET
```